# Reason why checking out from HEAD^ a file put it in staging area

Tags: git

Doing this test with git: I remove a file from the branch I'm in with

```
git rm rubbish.txt
git commit
```

so file disappear from file system and from tracking.
Then let's say I was wrong and I want to have back my file I do

```
checkout HEAD^ rubbish.txt
```

this works, I've back my file on file system, but it is already staged, why? if I checkout, let's say, a branch, I have the file system updated to that commit, but nothing in the stage area, why do I if I checkout a file?

Comment: @Schwern, I think the question is why the behaviour is different with branches and commits when it comes to checkout.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous I misread the problem.

Comment: "*if I checkout, let's say, a branch, I have the file system updated to that commit, but nothing in the stage area*" That's not true. See [`git help checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt): "*git checkout [<branch>] To prepare for working on <branch>, switch to it by **updating the index** and the files in the working tree*" (emphasize mine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason, that's how checking out single file works. [From the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

> `git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=<style>] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...`
>
> Overwrite the contents of the files that match the pathspec. When the
> `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit) is not given, overwrite working tree with the
> contents in the index. ***When the `<tree-ish>` is given, overwrite both the index
> and the working tree with the contents at the `<tree-ish>`.***

Note that [`git-restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) does not do this, by default it only updates the worktree. The equivalent command is `git restore --source HEAD^ --worktree --staged rubbish.txt`.

Comment: Note, too, that while `git checkout <tree-ish> -- <path>` writes to both index and work-tree, `git checkout -- <path>` does not, and this includes the `--ours` and `--theirs` options. It does all make sense, in an internal-to-Git point of view, but it's confusing to those new to Git, for sure.